# public void method in Startup.cs not running on build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is the code in my Startup.cs file and 2 of my three methods are running on build. However I added the bottom method **public void PackageRequestDataAccess** and for some reason its not running.

```
namespace Company.Shipping.Service
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
        private IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _environment = env;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Code Ran successfully here 
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
           //Code running successfully here
        }

        //Method below not running 
        public void PackageRequestDataAccess(Common.ServiceHost.WebHost.ServiceConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            IMongoCollection<PackageDataEntity> _reqrespcollection;
            MongoDBRepository<PackageDataEntity> _repo = new MongoDBRepository<PackageDataEntity>(configuration.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"]);

            _reqrespcollection = _repo.Collection;

            int _expiry = Convert.ToInt32(configuration.Settings["ShippingReqRespDataTTL"]);
            TimeSpan _ttl = new TimeSpan(0, 0, _expiry);
            CreateIndexOptions index = new CreateIndexOptions();
            index.ExpireAfter = _ttl;

            var _key = Builders<PackageDataEntity>.IndexKeys.Ascending("RequestSentOn");
            _reqrespcollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(_key);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to run all these three methods whenever the application starts.

Comment: How were you able to validate that any of the routines are running?  Are you certain of this?

Comment: What kind of project is this?

Comment: What makes you believe it should run from start? Do you call it? Are you expecting it to be called by aspnet core? I don't see anything related to this, so I am not sure what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: As per the documentation only the Configure and ConfigureServices are called during the startup. Is the third method user defined?

Comment: @Thangadurai yes I am certain these two are getting hit because of the break points I put are being hit. So appartently configure and ConfigureServices are the only ones that can be hit so I would have to place my method within one of these?

Comment: @Lostaunaum That depends on what you want to do in that method or you can call the third method from any one of the methods

Comment: @Thangadurai yes sir that is the answer. You can go ahead and post it as an answer since you are correct the only two methods that can be called from startup are Configure and Configure services. I am tweaking it a bit to make sure the third one runs from configureServices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the MSDN docs [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup) only the Configure and ConfigureServices are called during startup.

> The Startup class must include a Configure method and can optionally
>   include a ConfigureServices method, both of which are called when the
>   application starts.

In you case, may be you can add your logic to any one of this method or just call the method from the above method(s).